# MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax creating a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure using phpmyadmin.

This is my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM patient_data
WHERE patient_data.patient_id = p_id AND patient_data.date_of_birth = dob
```

See a screenshot of my window:
[image]

I get the following error:[image]

This is my `patient_data` table:[image]

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try dropping the second parameter and adding it again, you can see that it's missing from the SQL.

Comment: @NigelRen That is the solution! Thanks! Add it as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though there is some problem with creating the script from that dialog.  When you see the parameters being created, the second one is missing (and therefore an extra `,` with no field name.

The problem seems to have been cleared by deleting the second parameter and re-adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another parameter:

- Direction: OUT
- Name: **cl_cursor** (Can be any name you want)
- Type: SYS_REFCURSOR

In the code do the following:

```
open cl_cursor for
    SELECT * 
    FROM patient_data
    WHERE patient_id = p_id AND
          date_of_birth = dob;
```

---

If the above solution does not work try adding

```
begin

open cl_cursor for
    SELECT * 
    FROM patient_data
    WHERE patient_id = p_id AND
          date_of_birth = dob; 

end;
```

Comment: The system does not have `SYS_REFCURSOR` option in `Type`.